# Zend HTTP Client Invalid URI supplied?

Tags: php, url, zend-framework

I'm having trouble using Zend HTTP on a URL:

```
$bestBuyClient = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(search=pizza&salePrice>10&salePrice<15)?apiKey=MyKeyHere&page=1&numItems=10&format=json&show=sku&name&productId&type&regularPrice&salePrice&upc&modelNumber&image&largeFrontImage&mediumImage&thumbnailImage&largeImage&shortDescription&longDescription');
$response = $bestBuyClient->request();

$json="";
if($response->isSuccessful()){
    $jsonTxt=$response->getBody();
    $json = @json_decode($jsonTxt,true);
}
$jsonProducts=$json;
return $jsonProducts;
```

For some reason, this gives me an error:

```
Invalid URI supplied
```

Whats wrong this this specific url?

**Edit:** In PostMan or browser request sends proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change:

```
$bestBuyClient = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(search=pizza&salePrice>10&salePrice<15)?apiKey=MyKeyHere&page=1&numItems=10&format=json&show=sku&name&productId&type&regularPrice&salePrice&upc&modelNumber&image&largeFrontImage&mediumImage&thumbnailImage&largeImage&shortDescription&longDescription');
$response = $bestBuyClient->request();
```

To

```
$shoppableClient = new Zend_Http_Client(sprintf('https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products'."%s?%s", urlencode('(search=pizza&salePrice>10&salePrice<15)'), 'apiKey=MyKeyHere&page=1&numItems=10&format=json&show=sku&name&productId&type&regularPrice&salePrice&upc&modelNumber&image&largeFrontImage&mediumImage&thumbnailImage&largeImage&shortDescription&longDescription'));
```

**Please let me know if works :).**